# ASP.NET Core base url in config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In config file i have

```
  "HRServices": {
    "CarService": "https://stackoverflow.com/Cars/...",
    "EmployeesService": "https://stackoverflow.com/Employees/...",
    "FinanceService": "https://stackoverflow.com/Finance/...",
    ....
  }
```

Is it possible to specify base url for all those addresses?

To get something like

```
  "baseUrl":"https://stackoverflow.com",
  "HRServices": {
    "CarService": "baseUrl/Cars/...",
    "EmployeesService": "baseUrl/Employees/...",
    "FinanceService": "baseUrl/Finance/...",
    ....
  }
```

Update:

In controller it used:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Index()
{
    string url = _configuration["HRServices:EmployeesService"];
    ...
}


using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the root of an Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration hierarchy.
    public interface IConfigurationRoot : IConfiguration
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationProviders for this configuration.
        IEnumerable<IConfigurationProvider> Providers { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Force the configuration values to be reloaded from the underlying Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationProviders.
        void Reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on how you are retrieving those settings in your application. Can you give us more information?

Comment: That depends on your code that loads the configuration file.

Comment: Specify the baseUrl, as you have above, but remove `baseUrl` from all the paths and just add it in the code.  If you prefer, make a method for making requests and append the path to the baseUrl in there, so you only do it in one place.

Comment: In this case, not so much. It's wrong-headed to hard-code something like this. Something like a base URL is config, and should go in config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing that will do this for you automatically, but you can manually register your strongly typed config, and do it yourself:

```
services.AddScoped(p =>
{
    var config = p.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var baseUrl = config["baseUrl"]
    return new HRServicesConfig
    {
        CarService = baseUrl + config["HRServices:CarService"],
        EmployeeService = baseUrl + config["HRServices:EmployeeService"],
        FinanceService = baseUrl + config["HRServices:FinanceService"]
    }
});
```

The one catch, is that you won't be using `IOptions` anymore, so you'd inject `HRServicesConfig` directly, rather than something like `IOptions<HRServicesConfig>`. Some might consider that a feature, though.